# Coq produce instance of a type `{x : T | P x}` inside an explicit definition given an `x'` of type `T`

Tags: coq, beginner

I'm trying to formalize a simple type system in Coq as an exercise.

I have a type `Item` and a type `{x : Item | IsNormal Item}`. If `Sort` is a constructor of `Item` and `Sort` satisfies `IsNormal`, what's the most natural way to produce an instance of `{x : Item | IsNormal Item}` where the `Item` in question is `Sort`?

---

I have an inductive type called `Item` which might be a read of a free variable (in this case a free variable is an $\mathbb{N}$).

I want to introduce a distinction between terms that are headed by a variable read and terms that are definitely not headed by a variable.

I'm trying to use `sig types` for this (see [this answer](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/731) and [this link](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Specif.html)).

The thing I am having problems with is this definition. (I also tried a shorter version with `match x with | Read x' => env x' | _ => x end` as the body)

```
Definition in_env (env : nat -> NormalItem) (x : Item) : NormalItem :=
  match x with
  | Read x' => env x'
  | Sort => Sort
  | N => N
  | T => T
  | Nat n => Nat n
  end.
```

`NormalItem` is defined as `{ x : Item | IsNormal x }`, where `IsNormal` picks out the members of `Item` that are not headed by `Read`.

This definition doesn't type check (error shown below).

```
Error:
In environment
env : nat -> NormalItem
x : Item
The term "Sort" has type "Item" while it is expected to have type
 "NormalItem".
```

I think this is because `Sort` needs to instead be a pair consisting of an `Item` and a proof that the item in question satisfies `isNormal`. I cannot figure out, however, how to write such a thing.

##### Appendix A

````
Require Import Arith.
Require Import List.
Require Import Specif.
Require Import Notations.

Open Scope nat_scope.

Inductive Item : Type :=
| Sort : Item
| N : Item
| T : Item
| Nat : nat -> Item
| Read : nat -> Item
.

Definition IsNormal (a : Item) : Prop :=
  match a with
  | Read _ => False
  | _ => True
  end.

Definition NormalItem : Type := { x : Item | IsNormal x }.
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at how `{ x : A | P}` is defined (for instance using `Locate "{".` to find out it’s a notation for `sig` and `Print sig.` to see the definition of `sig`), you can see that to construct an inhabitant of `NormalItem` you indeed need to provide a pair (or, rather, two arguments) to the unique constructor `exists` of `sig`.

There are two ways to do this. The first one is to simply alter your definition to the following (I took the liberty of factoring out the branches as you suggested)

```
Definition in_env (env : nat -> NormalItem) (x : Item) : NormalItem :=
  match x with
  | Read x' => env x'
  | y => exist _ y I
  end.
```

here `I` is the only constructor of `True`, to which `IsNormal y` reduces to in those branches.

Now this works on this simple example because the proof you have to write by hand is very simple, but often you want to do a "mixed" definition, where you give some part of it in a direct way, but write down proofs interactively. You can do this by hand, relying on the `refine` tactic:

```
Definition in_env' (env : nat -> NormalItem) (x : Item) : NormalItem.
Proof.
  refine (
  match x with
  | Read x' => env x'
  | Sort => exist _ Sort _
  | N => exist _ N _
  | T => exist _ T _
  | Nat n => exist _ (Nat n) _
  end ).
  all: cbn ; auto.
Defined.
```

However, doing this by hand can get quite tedious quite fast. Happily, [Program](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/program.html) and [Equations](https://github.com/mattam82/Coq-Equations/) can help making this kind of definitions more natural.

Answer (score 1):

It is very unlikely that you really want to organize your formalization using predicates such as `IsNormal`. Instead you should define types that already carry precisely the correct information and use those.

I am guessing what you are doing, so for a better answer, please explain in your question what the Grand Plan of your formalization is.

```
Inductive NormalItem :=
  | Sort : NormalItem
  | N : NormalItem
  | T : NormalItem
  | Nat : nat -> NormalItem
.

Inductive Item : Type :=
  | Normal : NormalItem -> Item
  | Read : nat -> Item
.

Definition in_env (env : nat -> NormalItem) (x : Item) : NormalItem :=
  match x with
  | Read x' => env x'
  | Normal y => y
  end.
```